# Batch script to open putty and load uid and pwd in multiple screens

Tags: windows, batch-file, putty

I'm using PuTTY emulator to simulate load like RFGUN

> Load host window
>   enter username
>   enter password
>   enter username
>   enter password

```
@echo off 
start E:\apps\putty.exe -load "Putty" -ssh user1@123456 -pw 0987655
```

After this I need to enter one more user ID and password, (tried but it didn't worked).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) to conduct really high load onto the [SSH server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers), it's better to consider using a specialized load-testing tool which supports [SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol)

For example you can go for [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), there is [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler which allows establishing connectivity with the SSH server and running arbitrary commands. JMeter automatically measures elapsed time and builds nice [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) where you can correlate increasing load with the increasing response time/number of errors, etc.

Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) article for more information